# Rails view - on 'try' failure display something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have this variable:

```
@preview
```

Which is either a hash filled with wonderful data, or it is a string with some value like `preview is unavailable`.

I have this code here (slim / rails):

```
.well
  .preview-data
    - @preview.try(:each) do |line_number, line_data|
        .line#{line_number} = line_data
```

**How do I get the view to display a message if the `@preview.try(:each)` fails?**

What I've tried:

```
- if @preview.try(:each) 
    @preview.each do |line_number, line_data|
...
- else
    .preview-unavailable = @preview
```

which just displays the `@preview` data anyway.

Comment: There is a valid answer below, but in general I would suggest avoiding type checking. Having a variable be either X, Y or Z is going to give you some head aches. In your specific case I would rather return an empty hash, check for that, and print a message based on the result.

Comment: That is what I actually ended up doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- if @preview.is_a?(String)
    .preview-unavailable = @preview
- else
    @preview.each do ...
```

Comment: Does this 'go against' the point of Ruby Ducktyping? Does it matter if it works?

Comment: @Jeff, if you want to support duck typing, but know that, say, the `String` equivalent will never support the enumeration methods, you could instead test with `if @preview.respond_to?(:each)` and do the iterating on the true condition.